# MySQL/PHP - Select all the rows where column from table 1 is equal to column from table 2 and creating a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am searching for a way that i can select all the rows from MySQL table where column from table1 is equal to column from table 2.

Here is what i want to achieve describing it by code. I tried this but nothing happens.

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `table1.id`= `table2.id` ORDER by `table1.name` ASC;
```

And then when i select these rows i have to echo some of them into foreach loop, something like this:

```
<?PHP
foreach($results as $row){
echo $row['table1.name'];             
}
?>
```

Can you give me a correct way to make this thing happen as an answer to my question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use both tables in `FROM` part

```
SELECT * FROM `table1`, `table2` WHERE `table1.id`= `table2.id` ORDER by `table1.name` ASC;
```

Or use an `INNER JOIN` like this

```
    SELECT * FROM `table1` INNER JOIN `table2` ON `table1.id`= `table2.id` ORDER by `table1.name` ASC
```

& then fetch values like this, you do not need alias in $row[], but columns (or their respective aliases) must be unique

```
<?PHP
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `table1`, `table2` WHERE `table1.id`= `table2.id` ORDER by `table1.name` ASC";

    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    while($row = $mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        echo $row['name'];             
    }
?>
```

Answer assumes you have created a database connection named $conn

Comment: To clarify this: Both SQL statements do exactly the same, but the `inner join` is IMHO easier to understand.

Comment: use `PDO` and `fetchAll` which will return an array and use can use a `foreach` on that array. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql **join**

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` inner join table2 on `table1.id`= `table2.id` ORDER by `table1.name` ASC;
```

or full code is

```
<?PHP
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `table1` inner join table2 on `table1.id`= `table2.id` ORDER by `table1.name` ASC";

    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $row = $mysql_fetch_array($res);
    foreach($row as $rows){
    //Add colum name 
    echo $rows['name'];
    }

?>
```

Comment: The `$rows['name'];` is name from table1 or from table2, how can i understand that ?

Comment: Add an **alias** on every table like **table1.name as name1** in mysql query

Comment: Can you edit your answer with this in addition so i can mark your question as an answer!